# How to handle only one same document in multiple indices (indices are based on everyday)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

In my project,

I am fetching records from database and keeping document id as primary key id.

I have created indices based on date. So everyday new index has been created.
like, test-2019.09.23, test-2019.09.22

This logstash job runs every 5 minutes. This is requirement.

Now if records has been updated within a day then elasticsearch maintains it properly but if records has been updated on another day then it will be treated as a new document in new index.

This is creating issue as "**multiple duplicate records**" while searching and fetching the records.

**I want to handle one copy(or latest) of same document across indices.**

How to handle it?
Any configuration suggestions? or any sample example would be helpful.

Comment: You should define the logstash index based on some date field present in your data so that a record from 09.22 will always be written to that index and not to the latest one. Please share your Logstash configuration and we'll fix that.

Comment: @Val, But in this case, if date has been updated due to some change in data then it will change and after that it again falls into new index. any other option?

Comment: Of course, you'd need a date field that doesn't change, i.e. a date like createDate (when the record was created) and not like updateDate (when the record was modified)

Comment: Ok, got it. But Is there any other option rather then this? like, can we manage it in elasticsearch while adding data from logstash to elasticsearch? Because I can't change what you have suggested as of now in system.

Comment: "can we manage it in ES"... what do you mean by "it"? Logstash doesn't remember where it sent each record. The only way to be certain about the index distribution is by basing that distribution on the actual data. If you show a sample document and your Logstash config, it might help.

Comment: Ok. Let me come-up with sample data and config.